# Increase gap between every 2 rows in a table

Tags: html, css, angular

When I used the following code:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I got the below output :

[image]

But my required output is :

[image]

Tried to use margin for table tr..but there is no change.

Thanks..!!!

Comment: You should add HTML and CSS file too.

Comment: Yeah, don't make us guess what your structure is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Updated what I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, with a value of **2n+1** every 2 elements:

```
:nth-child(2n+1)
```

The fact is that you can set gap in a table only in the `table` tag - `border-spacing`. To use a `margin` and a `display: block` is rude in my opinion.

For the gap between the rows, I applied rule `border-top`, giving the border the **currentColor** color.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

table tr {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    color: white;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    border-top: 25px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How to achieve the same using table ?

Comment: @S.Reddi, I have updated the solution. Also, notice that I've added tags <thead> and <tbody>.